# How do I use textinput() in Turtle graphics for Python when I want to say more than one thing?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I would like to use `textinput()` to solicit from the user an x, y coordinate.
I look at what they've entered and if it's not valid input, I ask them for more input.

so let's say `xy = 3,2` and that isn't valid. I want to be able to say:

`turtle.textinput("", xy, "is not a valid input. Enter new x,y")`

However, this offers too many arguments but if I do something like the following, it puts {} around each aspect.

`turtle.textinput("", (ui, "is not a valid input. Enter new x,y"))`

Is there a ways to just get it to prompt nicely: "3,2 is not a valid input. Enter new x,y"? I haven't found much literature online.

Comment: Could a solution be something with formatted string liberals?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually kept playing and figured this out. I figured I'd leave the question up in case it helps someone else in the future.

Using formatted string liberals is the key!
I converted the pair to ints instead of strings within the list, then when I used textinput, instead of just having the second argument be a string, it was:

turtle.textinput("", f"{xy} is not a valid input. Enter new x,y")

Voila! :)